# PostStart hook seems to not work even though there is no failure

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod running a cassandra container. I want to create a keyspace once the container starts. I tried using the postStart hook. For some reason it does not fail but the keyspace does not get created. But I tried the same command in the readinessProbe as a hack and it worked fine. Can someone help me understand what's wrong with my configuration. Thanks in advance

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: local-cass-volume-1
  labels:
    type: local
    app: test
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /tmp/data/cass-volume-1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-cassandra
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 9042
  selector:
    app: test
    tier: cass
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: cass-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-cassandra
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
        tier: cass
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: cassandra:latest
        name: cassandra
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9042
          name: cass-port
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cass-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/cassandra
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command: ["cqlsh", "-e", "CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS     test1234 WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;"]
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 10
          failureThreshold: 5
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "until echo $'CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS test908 WITH replication = {\'class\': \'SimpleStrategy\', \'replication_factor\': \'1\'}  AND durable_writes = true;' | cqlsh ; do echo boo; sleep 2; done"]
      volumes:
      - name: cass-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: cass-pv-claim
```

Comment: Short debugging tip: If you have access to the kubelet logs, you see preStop hook errors. The error message looks like `preStop hook for container "fpm" failed: ...`

Comment: Are you asking me to test the command in the prestop hook So that I can see the logs ?
And in the events I don't see my postStart hook failing.

Comment: Sorry. I meant postStart hooks. AFIAK failed postStart hooks don't appear in the events neither in the container logs. That's why you need to take a look in the kubelet logs directly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue of postStart hook commands not executing. After went through this tried readinessProbe trick and it worked for me as well. The issue was, I am executing curl commands to which the same service should reply back. even though its postStart hook application needed a few more seconds to reply back. adding sleep command before executing curl commands solved my issue.